# One container with ranked profiles

Tags: html, css

I want to create a leaderboard but I stuck in this issue:

```css
.profiles-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 105%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
.profile {
  background: grey;
  width: 33%;
  height: 94px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="profiles-container">
  <div class="profile ">1</div>
  <div class="profile ">2</div>
  <div class="profile ">3</div>
  <div class="profile ">4</div>
  <div class="profile ">5</div>
  <div class="profile ">6</div>
  <div class="profile ">7</div>
  <div class="profile ">8</div>
  <div class="profile ">9</div>
  <div class="profile ">10</div>
</div>
```

As you see I have one `profiles-container` and I added the `profile`s inside it,

The issue is the ranks are in the same row, I want to rank like this instead:

[image]

I want it like leaderboard so I want it to rank first column the the second one right ?

Is the a solution to do it **without changing the structure of HTML code** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this works? I wrapped your profiles in another div with class name `profileMain` and gave `width: 49%`for it to keep 2 elements in same row and flexbox feature `justify-content: center` `align-items: center` to keep inner element in `center` of `49%`

```css
.profiles-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.profileMain {
  width: 49%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.profile {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: yellow;
  width: 180px;
  height: 194px;
  margin-bottom: 32px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="profiles-container">
  <div class="profileMain">
    <div class="profile ">1</div>
  </div> 
  <div class="profileMain">
    <div class="profile ">2</div>
  </div> 
  <div class="profileMain">
    <div class="profile ">3</div>
  </div> 
  <div class="profileMain">
    <div class="profile ">4</div>
  </div> 
  <div class="profileMain">
    <div class="profile ">5</div>
  </div> 
  <div class="profileMain">
    <div class="profile ">6</div>
  </div> 
  <div class="profileMain">
    <div class="profile ">7</div>
  </div> 
  <div class="profileMain">
    <div class="profile ">8</div>
  </div> 
  <div class="profileMain">
    <div class="profile ">9</div>
  </div> 
  <div class="profileMain">
    <div class="profile ">10</div>
  </div> 
</div>
```